# Will the new lightning EarPods work with iPad?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, headphones, lightning

The new iPhone 7 has no headphone jack, meaning that Apple has to release EarPods with a lightning connector. Will these new EarPods work with older devices? I'm assuming yes, since I'm *pretty* sure all the lightning cable has always included optional audio output, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am also on IPad Pro 12", but 9.3.5 beta because it's the one that fixes the Logitech Keyboard problem. The most current beta update is 9.3.5 for that Logitech CREATE Keyboard. So.... I can't use the Lightning headphone jack! Whatever you do, don't buy the Logitech CREATE keyboard, it scratches your screen and now you can't use the Lightning earbuds. Apple and Logitech, you two need to get your shit together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The System Requirements from [EarPods with Lightning Connector](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMTN2AM/A/earpods-with-lightning-connector) states:

> Works with all devices that have a Lightning connector and support iOS
>   10 or later, including iPod touch, iPad, and iPhone.
>
> Compatibility
>
> **iPhone Models**
>
> iPhone 5
> iPhone 5c
> iPhone 5s
> iPhone SE
> iPhone 6
> iPhone 6 Plus
> iPhone 6s
> iPhone 6s Plus
> iPhone 7
> iPhone 7 Plus 
>   
> **iPad Models**
>
> iPad with Retina display
> iPad mini 2
> iPad Air
> iPad Air 2
> iPad mini 3
> iPad mini 4
> iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
> iPad Pro (12.9-inch)
>   
>  **iPod Models**
>
> iPod touch 6th Generation

Comment: IIRC iPod Touch 5G has a lightning connector, but is not listet as compatible.

Comment: @Max Ried, You'll have to take that up with Apple as what I posted is a quote from the included link within the answer. Additionally if you go to [http://www.apple.com/ios/ios-10/](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios-10/) and near the bottom of the page in the **iOS 10 is compatible with these devices** section for **iPod** it too states "iPod touch 6th generation" as the only iPod compatible with iOS 10, which is one of the requirements to use the EarPods with Lightning Connector with an iDevice that uses the Lightning Connector.

Comment: Ah, ok. I missed that point.

Answer (score 1):

Just got new lightning earphones, but when I tried plugging into iPad, played through speakers.

Fix: shut down iPad, restart with lightning earphones plugged in (I'm not sure if that is really required, but it worked for me). Sound now plays through lightning earphones on iPad (iPad Pro 12", iOS 10.2).

Comment: This would probably work better as a comment, not an answer.